# How do I change text color on the selected row inside a ListView/GridView? (using Expression Dark theme)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, styling

I'm using theExpression Dark WPF Theme(http://wpfthemes.codeplex.com/) with a ListView(view property set to a GridView) to display some user data like the following :

```
<ListView
      Grid.Row="1"
      ItemsSource="{Binding RegisteredUsers}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}"
      > 
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn            
            Header="Login"
            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Login}"
            Width="60"/>
          <GridViewColumn
            Header="Full Name"
            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FullName}"
            Width="180"/>
          <GridViewColumn
            Header="Last logon"
            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastLogon}"
            Width="120"/>
          <GridViewColumn
            Header="Photo"
            Width="50">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <Image 
                  Source="{Binding Photo}" 
                  Width="30" 
                  Height="35"/>
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

The rows have white text with a dark background and white background when selected, however the text color doesnt change when selected and it makes very difficult to read, I would like the text to have a dark color when the row is selected. I have searched for a way to style the text color but with no success, here is the control template for the ListViewItem :

```
<Border SnapsToDevicePixels="true" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2" x:Name="border">

            <Grid Margin="2,0,2,0">
              <Rectangle x:Name="Background" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0.25" Fill="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
              <Rectangle x:Name="HoverRectangle" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Fill="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
              <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedRectangle" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Fill="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
              <GridViewRowPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Margin="0,2,0,2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </Grid>

</Border>
```

The trigger that changes the background color simply applies an animation to change  the 'SelectedRectangle' opacity, but I cant change the text color on the same trigger(I tried using a setter for the foreground color on the ListViewItem, but with no success).

Does someone have a clue on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve by applying a textblock style on the GridViewRowPresenter scope :

```
<GridViewRowPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Margin="0,2,0,2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                <GridViewRowPresenter.Resources>
                                    <Style        
                                        TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"
                                        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}"
                                        >      
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger
                                                Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"
                                                Value="True">
                                                <Setter 
                                                    Property="Foreground"
                                                    Value="Black"
                                                    />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>                                                                             
                                    </Style>
                                </GridViewRowPresenter.Resources>
                            </GridViewRowPresenter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the TextBlock.Foreground

```
 <GridViewRowPresenter TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
```